# Правильный выбор breakpoint css

Tags: html, css

в psd макетах: Десктоп - ширина контейнера 1180px, мобильные - ширина контейнера 420px. Думаю, что проще будет, с учетом распространенных разрешений экранов взять одну точку - 1200px. Всё что меньше - будет выглядеть как на макете для мобильных, всё что больше - макет десктоп. Для промежуточных значений, например для планшетов или маленьких мониторов будет сложно адаптировать т.к контент специфический, всякая графика, блоки в нужном порядке. Правильно ли я выбрал breakpoint?

Comment: Ну, строго говоря, в этом вопросе нет понятия "правильно" - всё зависит от поставленных задач. В принципе, в том же бутстрапе есть такой брейкпоинт - max-width 1199px. Типа всё, что больше (от 1200), - десктоп. Можете считать, что это "правильно" :))

Comment: Не хватит одного брейкпоинта под нормальную верстку. Как миниму 320px еще нужен, потому что на маленьких экранах надо убирать все лишнее

Answer (score 0):

Средние значения обычно такие: 
// Small smartphones
$screen-xs: 360px;

// Small tablets and large smartphones
$screen-sm: 767px;

// Tablets and small desktops
$screen-md: 1080px;

// Large tablets and desktops
$screen-lg: 1200px;